# How can i get push notifications from a web service to my windows wpf application

Tags: c#, windows, amazon-web-services, push-notification, wns

I want to receive push notifications from a web service and show it in user's desktop/laptop in the form of a tile/ toast. Can this be achieved using WNS

Comment: If it is an ordinary WPF-Application and it needs to be via WNS, then no. At least up until the last time, I researched ~ October 2018.

Comment: is there any other alternative to receiving notifications apart from using windows ser